# Migration MySQL to Cloud Environment replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I'm having 5 MySQL database server , these  5 server are used for e-business web-server. Now I Would like to move the MySQL database to cloud environment for database continuous running. Recently we face hardware failure (misc), in future we need to avoid any failure the database should continuously up and running that is the main objective

Guys could you suggest best way to proceed this scenario ?

Comment: Try setting up replication first and then switch over to cloud

Answer (score -1):

we already done the master & master replication in locally , so can any one recommended to which cloud is best for my query like (AWS , Openstack,SoftlayerCloud ) on it.